# OnClick changes TD cell color. How can I click to change it back?

Tags: javascript

I have a button and when I click on this button I need to highlight the highest and lower values of my html table.

I set the background color of my highest table cell in this way and this works ok:

```js
$HighElementToMark.css('background-color', HigherNumberColor);
```

How can i get the color assigned to `$HighElementToMark`?

I thought to use something like:

```js
alert(HighElementToMark.style.backgroundColor);
```

But it doesn't work.

In addition I need to reset the color of my table cell when I click again on my button.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Once it is set like that, `$HighElementToMark.css('background-color')` should return the current color. It's not necessarily suitable for comparisons though. To reset the color, use `$HighElementToMark.css('background-color', '');` (the alert you tried doesn't work because `$HighElementToMark` is a jQuery object; `.style` is a property of a regular HTMLElement though)

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/L6mjk82x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.style` is a setter only, meaning you can only set the style. In order to read the current style you can use `getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor`.
In order to keep track of the changes you might want to set a variable as a flag like `isChange`. But as we can't see your actual implementation it's hard to suggest anything truly useful

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the color in the following ways:

```
document.getElementById("HighElementToMark").style.backgroundColor 

$HighElementToMark.css('background-color')
```

Both of them will return the `background-color` property of the style. If you think about `element.style` as a setter only:

> To return style properties:
>     *element*.style.*property*
>     To set style properties:
>   *element*.style.*property = value*
>   **Note:** It will only work on inline style declarations.

As for the toggling between colors, let's say we keep a boolean `colorChange` flag:

```
{  // we do this when button is clicked.
     colorChange = !colorChange; 

     var colorToSet = colorChange ? HigherNumberColor : SomeOtherColor;
     $HighElementToMark.css('background-color', colorToSet);
     console.log( $HighElementToMark.css('background-color') );
 }
```

This way we can use to the flag to track the toggling of the colors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 75%;
        }
        table > tbody > tr td{
            background-color: #f44242;
        }

        .toggle{
            background-color: #024405;
        }
    </style>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <table >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Column A
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Column B
                        </th>
                        <th>
                        Column C
                            </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id = "highlightMe" >9</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table><br/>
        <button type="button" id="highlighter" >Highlight Me</button>

        <script>
            (function(window, document, undefined){
                var toggledColor = '#024405';
                $('#highlighter').click(function(){
                    var $HighElementToMark = $('#highlightMe'); //or your algorithm to identify the correct highest value td

                    /* Method 01 - toggling manually */
                    //$HighElementToMark.css('background-color', !$HighElementToMark.data('hasOriginalBG') ? toggledColor: '') ; //toggle background color
                    //$HighElementToMark.data('hasOriginalBG', ($HighElementToMark.data('hasOriginalBG') ? false : true)); //persist the current status

                    /* Method 02 - toggling using jquery togleclass */
                    //$HighElementToMark.toggleClass('toggle') ;  // you can also use jquery toggle class for this 
                });
            })(window, document);
        </script>
</body>
```